# How to use a value in specific value to find the index python

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QszRL.png)

Is there any method to get the index according to the specific value of "Adj Close".Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This shoud do the job

```
val = 38.351017
df[df['Adj Close'] == val].index
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!